# How old is Drek'thar?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I very much enjoy [alterac valley](http://www.wowwiki.com/Alterac_Valley), until recently I hadn't known much about drek'thar. After going back in time to draenor I met him and also encountered [Mulverick](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=13181/wing-commander-mulverick). This made me curious about how old Drek'thar is.

I searched around and found this: [Drek'thar Cutscene](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/774443-Drek-thar-Cutscene), but it doesn't seem to hold an answer.

How old is Drek'thar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no definite answer.  But given lore, he was around before the legion presence on Draenor.  Given Thrall is in his 20s and Drek is indeed a Chieftain, drek is most likely in his 50s at Garrosh Heallscreams Fall.

Comment: Mentioned on the forums that Draenor is set 30 years ago [Destroy Draenor So Outland Can Exist?](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/12618236538#3)

Comment: Hmm no its 35.  Blizzard has even confirmed that.

Comment: Draenor is not set in the past at all, it is an alternate timeline version of the world that was created when Garrosh and Kairoz went back  in time and convinced the orcs not to drink the blood of Mannoroth (among other things). This all takes place in the War Crimes novel.

Comment: @Phaeze That's interesting, thanks for the information. I'm not too sure what an alternate timeline is, it's like a world that has the same people but where different things occur? I always thought that draenor was in the past, specially since durotan is thralls dad and Drek'Thar looks a bit younger in the cutscenes than he does in alterac valley.

Comment: @Alex An alternate timeline is a different version of the original world. It is the exact copy of the original until a certain point, where a different situation occurred, and so creating an alternate timeline.
Imagine someone went into a copy of our world at the time of Hitler and killed him when he was still a young boy, the world of today would be totally different but would still be our world, that's how you create an alternate timeline.